# Synergy 1.4.5 Require hotkey to switch screen

Tags: hotkeys, synergy

I've moved today from synergy 1.3.8 to 1.4.5 because of issue [#36](http://synergy-foss.org/tracker/issues/36), but I'm missing a feature, on version 1.3.8 I could set it up so that it would not switch screen unless Ctrl key was pressed. Using the new hotkey setup from version 1.4.5 I wasn't able to accomplish that. Any tips/suggestions?